# Unable to create more classes in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am fairly new to coding in visual studio but I have found a wierd error of sorts. I've tried to google diffrent solutions but with no luck.

I am creating a `web API` for a client using Visual Studio. I've added my C# code in a class, saved it and all that went well.

When I was creating my repository for this code, also in a C# class that's when I  experienced the problem. Once I saved the class it automatically changes to `"~rf102E16D.TMP"` for no reason whatsoever. When I look at the location of my project I can find the C# source file but when I open it I and save the changes the same thing happens. I am unable to find the tmp files at the location of the project as well.

Comment: what kind of repository? Also is VS legal or not

Comment: legal VS. Just a normal repository, trying to call the string from the class

Comment: check access rights to your project's folder and ensure your source files are not readonly.

Comment: done, I am listed as the owner and got full control

Comment: Try disabling your Antivirus then opening visual studio again,  you may be running in a sandbox.

Comment: stupid question - but are the files write protected.  If you're using source control of some kind this could cause the files to be read only...

Comment: @RonBeyer I tried that, still got the same problem.

Comment: @C.Knight They're not write protected

Comment: The got solved somehow, I have no idea how. But I am not one to complain. Thanks for your help guys ! :)